# Do the Lively Kernel folks provide anonymous/read only SVN access to their latest builds?

Tags: smalltalk

I've been trying to find a copy of lively kernel on git, and it seems it's not available on there. Is the source to LK available on any other public-access SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have it posted on `lively-kernel.org/development`. Try `svn co http://www.lively-kernel.org/repository/lively-kernel/trunk/source/kernel/ lk_trunk`

Answer (score 4):

Development in Lively Kernel is rather different from conventional Web development since all development takes place online in a wiki (http://lively-kernel.org/webwerkstatt). This wiki is SVN-based and can be checked out but usually there is no need for this.

Please note that the repository at http://lively-kernel.org/repository/lively-kernel/ does not contain a recent Lively version.

Also, a new version of Lively will be released soon (source code).

Comment: Is the repository for the wiki accessible anonymously? Also, is it possible to obtain a log of recent commits and/or changes from the wiki?

Comment: Yes, read access is not restricted. You can get a SVN change log using svn log http://lively-kernel.org/repository/webwerkstatt/. This is probably not useful because of the WebDAV auto commit messages. A better alternative is to use a Lively tool ("LatestChangesViewer") here: http://lively-kernel.org/repository/webwerkstatt/ChangeLog.xhtml.